# How can I use Drupal.behaviors to notify H5P that it resizes itself?

Tags: jquery, h5p, drupal-behaviors, drupal-10

I don't have experience with Drupal.
We had migrated from Drupal 7. There was a functionality which sets all elements to `display: none;` and after clicking on certain buttons parts of the site become visible.

With the switch to Drupal 10 everything has been integrated into `Drupal.behaviors`.

Now I have to add some H5P elements. Since the first load of the site starts with `display: none;` the height of the H5P elements becomes 0px.

I found this [document describing my troubles](https://h5p.org/manipulating-h5p-with-javascript).

But I can't make this work in our `Drupal.behaviors`.

Here is some code which works similar:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach : function(context, settings) {
      once('these-tabs', 'these_buttons', context).forEach((these_buttons) => {
        $(".switcher_link").click(function () {
          $(".paragraph").hide();
          $(".paragraph").removeClass("activated");
          $(".paragraph-with-h5p-elem").fadeIn();
          $(".paragraph-with-h5p-elem").addClass("activated");
        });
        [...]
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

If I click on the button and start the Webdeveloper tools in my browser it works just fine. But if I do not activate the tools it shows no H5P content. So I guess the H5P needs to get a notification that it should resize itself. Which happens during the refresh triggered by the Webdeveloper tools.

I tried to add the following:

```
          [...]
          $(window).trigger("resize");
          [...]
```

```
          [...]
          $(this).trigger("resize");
          [...]
```

both seem not to notify the H5P handler.

If I try to activate the H5P function described [here](https://h5p.org/manipulating-h5p-with-javascript):

```
          [...]
          ui.newPanel.css('height', 'auto');
          H5P.jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
          [...]
```

it just tells me that there is no package "ui" or "H5P" known. They are not part of the namespace.
But "importing" them by simply adding `})(jQuery, Drupal, H5P);` doesn't work either.

When I try:

```
          [...]
          $(window).reload();
          [...]
```

it tells me that "reload" is not a function.

The solution seems so simple: Notify H5P that it should resize itself again.
But I can't get it to work in Drupal.behaviors yet.

**EDIT**
Thank you, [Oliver Tacke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9453575/oliver-tacke). But unfortunately you missed the point.
To be more clear:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
        attach : function(context, settings) {
            once('these-tabs', 'these_buttons', context).forEach((these_buttons) => {
                $(".switcher_link").click(function () {
                $(".paragraph").hide();
                $(".paragraph").removeClass("activated");
                $(".paragraph-with-h5p-elem").fadeIn();
                $(".paragraph-with-h5p-elem").addClass("activated");
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".switcher_link").on("click", function () {
                        console.log("Link for H5P activated!");
                        $(".paragraph-with-h5p-elem").height("1337px");
                        H5P.jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
                    });
                });
            });
        [...]
```

Doesn't work with Drupal.behaviors. It should resize by clicking the button with class "switcher_link" the second time. The output in the log reads "Link for H5P activated!". So the event listener works as intended.
Even the height is set properly. **But** the video will not be shown.

So my message: "the workaround presented by H5P people doesn't work with Drupal.behaviors" holds true nevertheless.

Meanwhile I had some insights about this: `H5P.instances` stays empty! It should at least be filled with the object found in `H5PIntegration.contents`. IMHO that's why it doesn't do anything during `H5P.jQuery(window).trigger('resize');`.

The remaining questions:

1. Did I get it right: `H5P.instances` should contain at least one object?
   -> <s>I had proven that `H5P.instances` needs to contain at least one H5P object. Whenever I use H5P outside of the buttons modification it fills `H5P.instances`.</s> Not in every case: There seem to be exceptions to it.
   <s>2. Why does `H5P.instances` stays empty by using `Drupal.behaviors`?</s>

**EDIT2:**
By reimplementing this in `jQuery` without `Drupal.behaviors` everything is shown except for H5P. Until I change anything in the browser (webdeveloper tools on/off, switching fullscreen in browser, and so on). I thought it doesn't work with `Drupal.behaviors` in Drupal 10. But I doesn't work with `jQuery`, too.
After this I tested different browsers: Same problem.
Afterwards I changed H5P content from interactive video to other content: Everything worked as intended! Switching back: H5P keeps missing.
This smells like a bug.

**EDIT3:**
After using `console.log(document); console.log(window);` in a javascript 'debug' modul I could track down some details.

In `drupal/web/modules/h5p/vendor/h5p/h5p-core/js/h5p.js` I inserted `console.log("H5P.instance.push: ", instance); console.log("H5P.instances: ", H5P.instances);` directly after `H5P.instance.push(instance);` (around line 369). I refer to this by `[1]`.
And in the jQuery from us I inserted the line `if (document.readyState === "complete") { setTimeout(() => {console.log("H5P.instances: ", H5P.instances);}, 2000); };`. I refer to this by `[2]`.

***If I use the Hello World example `Greeting card`:***

`[1]` "instance" shows:

```
Object { options: {…}, id: 17, "$": {…}, contentId: 17, libraryInfo: {…} }
​
"$": Object { 0: {…}, length: 1 }
​
contentId: 17
​
id: 17
​
libraryInfo: Object { versionedName: "H5P.GreetingCard 1.0", versionedNameNoSpaces: "H5P.GreetingCard-1.0", machineName: "H5P.GreetingCard", … }
​
options: Object { greeting: "Hello world!", image: {…} }
​
<prototype>: Object { on: on(type, listener, thisArg), once: once(type, listener, thisArg), off: off(type, listener), … }
h5p.js:370:13
```

and "H5P.instances" shows

```
H5P.instances:  
Array [ {…} ]
​
0: Object { options: {…}, id: 17, contentId: 17, … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
h5p.js:371:13
```

`[2]` shows:

```
H5P.instances:  
Array [ {…} ]
​
0: Object { options: {…}, id: 17, contentId: 17, … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
our_jquery.js:28:36
```

This resizes without any problems. I even do not need to insert extra code: It resizes automatically by setting the `display: block; height: 400px;` to parent node.

***If I use `Single Choice Set`:***

`[1]` "instance" shows:

```
H5P.instances.push:  
Object { contentId: 18, contentData: {…}, userResponses: [], on: on(type, listener, thisArg), once: once(type, listener, thisArg), off: off(type, listener), trigger: trigger(event, eventData, extras), order: (10) […], setBehaviour: setBehaviour(options), setVideo: setVideo(params), … }
h5p.js:370:13
```

and `H5P.instances` contains:

```
H5P.instances:  
Array [ {…} ]
​
0: Object { contentId: 18, contentData: {…}, userResponses: [], … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
h5p.js:371:13
```

But `[2]` shows only:

```
H5P.instances:  
Array []
​
length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []
our_jquery.js:28:36
```

Resize does not work in this case.

***My impression is that:***

1. `H5P.instances` should contain elements because everytime it finds HTML tags with class `.h5p-content` it fills `H5P.instances` and `H5PIntegration.contents` (defined in h5p-integration.js) with different object formats (see lines 58 and 59 in `h5p.js`). Indeed it does in every tested case but didn't hold for the cases where the resize didn't work. This makes sense because `H5P.trigger(` in `h5p.js` is only defined for `instance`. Verbatim: `H5P.trigger(instance, 'resize');` (lines 127, 129, 319, 330, 361, 364, 376, 568, 585, 1011, 1359, 1361, 1391 and 1445).
2. `H5P.instances` seems to just keep objects formatted in a certain way. Everything else seems to get erased. The formatting problem of the object arises by getting `var instance; ...` (line 929 - 969).

I wonder why this happens.

Comment: I don't think there's a bug on H5P's side - I set up Drupal 10 incl. the H5P plugin, added some custom module adding some `behaviors, ` and resizing works as expected. When you toggle the developer tools and go to full screen, that's what H5P core registers as a `resize` event and obviously works on your end, too. So there may be a bug, but potentially not in H5P but your setup.

Comment: `H5P.instances` will not be set in all contexts if I recall correctly. If there would really be a bug here, H5P would not show up at all, not even when you resize the viewport.

Comment: My environment is a `Drupal 10.1.5` with `h5p-2.0.0-alpha4`. Does this explain the different experience between us?

Comment: The operating system doesn't play a role. And while the plugin is labeled alpha, it has been labeled that for Drupal 9 the whole time, yet it has been used in production even without problems. One cannot rule out bugs introduced when porting to 10, but given that those were minor, I doubt it.

Comment: I didn't talk about OS. I was just curious whether our environments differ. From `h5p-2.0.0-alpha3` to `h5p-2.0.0-alpha4` the file `application.js` changed. Because `H5P.instances` looks like (a part of) the problem I reinstall `alpha3` and test with this to rule out possible regression bugs.

Comment: With `alpha3` I experience the same problems. So regressions are ruled out.

Comment: You mentioned your OS, so I  commented on that. Not sure why that seems to be bothering. As mentioned on the H5P forum (where a discussion like this should continue, not on StackOverflow), H5P.instances is not expected to set outside of the H5P content iframe, only inside. Some content types do not use an iframe, then you'll find everything in the top document context as well. But the behavior is normal. I suggest you paste a link to a site where your experience could be reproduced on the H5P forum.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pasting code without actually trying to understand what it does. That's not what I think StackOverflow is supposed to foster. So let's try to help you without giving a free consulting job providing the complete solution ...

When your `attach` callback is run, the [DOM's `readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) can still be `loading`. That means that not all of the page has been built yet, in particular the `H5P` object may not have been put into the `window` context. You will need to check for the `readyState` value and only proceed if it is `interactive` (at least). Even then, you may still want to check for the H5P object being available if your attach function is not only run for Drupal content that can contain H5P contents.

Once H5P is loaded, the H5P core will listen for `resize` events on the `window` and forward them to the H5P content type instances. You have already found a way to trigger such a `resize` event (`$(window).trigger('resize');` or `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));` in vanilla JavaScript without relying on a framework such as jQuery). You can [learn more about H5P and its resizing mechanism](https://snordian.de/2023/09/30/what-is-it-with-h5p-and-this-resizing/) by the way.

You will want to wait until an H5P content instance has been instantiated. Otherwise, triggering a `resize` event will not have an effect. You can achieve that by using H5P's event dispatcher that will fire an `initialized` event whenever an H5P content on a page was initialized. You can do this like so:

```
H5P.externalDispatcher.on('initialized', () => {
  // Do what needs to be done whenever H5P content was initialized ...
});
```

You mentioned that the container that holds the H5P iframe may not be able to gain height (as the CSS `display` property was set to `none`). You will need to make sure that has been changed before triggering a `resize`. Otherwise, the H5P iframe cannot gain height either even if the content inside resized.

Additionally, you may want to make sure that your whole callback is only run once due to [how Drupal uses the `attach` function](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview). Otherwise you may trigger a `resize` multiple times which would not break anything, but a `resize` can be expensive as it may trigger lots of computations.

Hope this will help you to figure out a solution.